# US domestic flight without passport for a foreigner

Tags: air-travel, usa, passports

I’m a foreign student and I lost my passport. I’d like to travel from Chicago to New York by plane. Can I use a copy of my passport or my student card as an ID?

I checked the TSA website already.

Comment: I checked that link and it doesn't answer my question, the guy is a us citizen and has driving license which I don't have

Comment: ok, this one does: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10226/travelling-within-the-us-as-a-british-citizen-without-a-passport?rq=1

Comment: "Also I checked the TSA website already." well, what did it tell you? http://www.tsa.gov/traveler-information/acceptable-ids

Comment: @MarkMayo done,

Comment: Not a duplicate as the other question involves a person who has a British driver's license -- this fellow apparently only has a student ID.

Comment: @RoboKaren The answers to the other question are sufficiently general and answer this question without any need for interpretation, including a link the TSA's list of acceptable ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the TSA Screening process, you will be asked for valid picture ID to ensure it matches your ticket.  If you don't have a picture ID, you will be turned back. If you present a fake ID, you will be turned back (if not arrested).

The question is whether or not the photocopy of the passport will suffice.  There, the one thing I can say with certainty is that the guy who checks your ID will be the one to make the call.  He might get it right, He might get it wrong, but if you don't pass him, you don't pass.

Personally, I doubt he'd take the copy - especially since I see them examining my documents for authenticity all the time. You can't do that with a photocopy, and if I were the guy, I wouldn't deviate from the routine.  If you're lucky, he might ask his boss, but all in all, your only real option is to get real documentation fast.