# I am flying to another state for a visa interview and am leaving my passport there, how can I fly back?

Tags: visas, air-travel, usa

I am flying in 10 days to another state to apply for a travel visa. As a foreigner, my passport is the only ID I have at the moment. How will I be able to travel back to my current state?

Will a photocopy of my passport and American visa, perhaps a letter, driver's license, and/or a temporary state ID work? (I don't think I will be able to get my state ID in time!)

Comment: You won't be able to fly: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20934/us-domestic-flight-without-passport-for-a-foreigner?rq=1

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate, unfortunately for you you can't travel without the passport, being a foreign citizen.  However, a British friend lost his in Texas, and still managed to talk his way onto the flight to New York, so it might be possible if you're really good at convincing (he is a salesman). I wouldn't risk it though.

Comment: I would see if you can get a non-driver's-license (NDL) state ID before you fly.

Comment: @MarkMayo If the answers to the other question are correct, foreigners living in the US will be unable to get visas for other countries unless they live close enough to a consulate to get there without flying.  I've voted to reopen the question.

Comment: @phoog I see your point . Let's edit the question.

Comment: Does the application process really require leaving the passport at the time of the interview?  I have sent my passport by courier on several occasions to receive a visa (albeit without an actual interview required)

Comment: @PeterM good point: it might be possible to say to the consulate that you need your passport to fly home, and that you'll send it to them as soon as you get there.

Comment: I don’t know about most countries, but a Spanish consulate will let you keep your passport if you have a good reason and let them have a copy.  But then you have to go back to the consulate when they are ready to put in the visa.

Comment: This type of problem can be a reason for your country to allow you to apply for a second passport.

Answer (score 4):

Without your foreign Passport or an ID issued in the United States, there is no way to guarantee you will be able to pass through TSA.

You may be able to pass TSA without ID as described here: [Forgot Your ID?](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification)

Unfortunately, there is no way to know if they can/will allow you to pass without actually trying.

Comment: It might help to have a receipt for the passport issued by the consulate processing the visa application.

Comment: @phoog I'd combine that with a photocopy of the info page of the passport.  No guarantees, though.