# Can I use a US citizenship certificate to fly withing the US?

Tags: air-travel, usa, us-citizens

I was born and currently live in México but I just recently received my US citizenship. I want to fly from Brownsville, Tx to Houston, Tx, so it is a domestic fly. Can I board with my citizenship certificate? I always enter the US by car using my citizenship certificate and never have a problem about it. PS. My trip is in December 11th, so I can't receive my US passport in time for the trip.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Travelling within the US as a foreign citizen without a passport](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10226/travelling-within-the-us-as-a-foreign-citizen-without-a-passport)

Comment: I disagree about it being a duplicate. The related question is about citizens of foreign countries in the US. This question is about a Naturalized (I think) US Citizen without a passport.

Comment: @CGCampbell: The list off acceptable IDs is the same regardless, and the top-voted answer on both questions link to the exact same list of IDs. Seems pretty duplicate to me.

Answer (score 8):

What is needed is an acceptable photo ID, e.g., a Mexico passport if you also have one of those. Your citizenship is not relevant on a domestic flight. From the [official list](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification), there are also other IDs you may already have.

Comment: I have my INE (The voting ID you receive when you're 18 here), but since it is mexican I don't think they would allow me to use it within the US. Even if my certificate does have a picture, is it still not relevant=

Comment: @Cecilia The certificate has your photo, so it _might_ be accepted. But you should obtain your US passport (or a passport card) as soon as you can.

Comment: @Cecilia if you have a Mexican passport you should use that.  I am a dual citizen and I routinely use my foreign passport for the TSA check.

Comment: @Cecilia You are *likely* to be OK with your existing documents. At the link I previously gave, there is an explanation what to do if you 'forgot' your ID. Your citizenship documentation includes your photo, as does your INE. Together that should suffice but they make no promises. Allow extra time, because you will probably get special questioning.

Comment: @Cecilia if you show your Mexican passport you should not get any special questioning from the TSA since that is a listed document.  If the border patrol is there, they'll want proof of your immigration status, which your citizenship certificate is.  You should have no trouble if you use those documents in combination.

Comment: Thank you all so much! I'm now definitely going to book my flight and do all of that!

Answer (score 6):

Your citizenship status does not matter for domestic flights. All you need is a form of identification document that is [accepted by the TSA](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification).

If you have one of those in hand, you can fly.