# How to fly within US without Passport/ID/Driver license?

Tags: usa, tsa, tsa-precheck

I just turned 18 recently, I have neither of those above and any main form of ID.

Can I use my school ID, Naturalized Citizenship certificate, and Vaccination card to fly within US? Specifically LA to Boston, if that information heleps.

Comment: Here is the list of documents https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification

If your naturalized citizenship certificate shows a photo, that seems like the most relevant one. This may be related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/59233/can-i-use-a-us-citizenship-certificate-to-fly-withing-the-us

Otherwise, I don't think you can use a school ID or a vaccination card as those are not listed.

Comment: @ComputerScientist: Certificate of Naturalization is not on that list

Comment: @DN: Do you have a passport of another country? Can you get a state ID, of the state where you reside, before the trip?

Comment: A **Certificate of Naturalization** is an important document that should be stored safely (i.e. you should not carry it around which could lead it to be damaged, lost or otherwise destroyed). Consider getting a passport card if a state ID is not possible.

Comment: I can not get a State ID, my trip will be within 5 days

Comment: I will not bring my certificate of naturalization then, I will bring my Social security card, School ID, and hope for the best.

Answer (score 5):

You don’t actually need ID, as there is a backup procedure for people without ID, but it does make things more difficult.

TSA [tell us](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification):

> In the event you arrive at the airport without valid identification, because it is lost or at home, you may still be allowed to fly. The TSA officer may ask you to complete an identity verification process which includes collecting information such as your name, current address, and other personal information to confirm your identity. If your identity is confirmed, you will be allowed to enter the screening checkpoint. You will be subject to additional screening, to include a patdown and screening of carry-on property.
>
> You will not be allowed to enter the security checkpoint if your identity cannot be confirmed, you choose to not provide proper identification or you decline to cooperate with the identity verification process.
>
> TSA recommends that you arrive at least two hours in advance of your flight time.

Bring any form of identification you may have, especially anything with a picture.

In the longer term, if you don’t plan to get a driver’s licence soon, get a passport or passport card, that should be quick and will save you a lot of hassle.

Comment: Or a state-issued non-driver identification card.

Comment: Not the use of the word "may". They can try to identify you, but they can also sent you away if they don't feel like it.

Comment: @Hilmar or, probably more likely, if their "identity verification process" for identifying people without Real ID isn't satisfied.  One thing they do, in my experience, is use a service that relies on data held by credit reporting agencies.  An 18-year-old may not have sufficient credit history for that to work.  I have no idea what they do if it doesn't work; they keep their cards very close to their chest here, for obvious reasons.  But it seems unlikely that they would make life so difficult for someone who has recently turned 18.